# Alexa on AV receiver with HDMI

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I'm using an Echo Dot to listen to radio, Spotify or Amazon Music. Thus I plugged it to the cinch-input of my AV receiver. But I don't want to switch the AV to the cinch input every time I want to hear to music.

Is there a way to switch directly to the correct input source (cinch) or an other easy workaround?
An optimal solution would switch it to cinch every time I start Alexa and every time I say "Alexa stop" it would switch back to the standard source (maybe with IFTTT).

---

**EDIT**

I'm using an Onkyo TX-SR313 AV-Receiver: [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0077V8930)

Comment: What model is your AV receiver? I think the answer probably depends on that.

Comment: ty :) i added the description

Comment: Related problems: https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/358 & https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/414 & https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/563 ; The problem is that your AV receiver basically speaks HDMI & Infrared and the Echo speaks WiFi and the base functionality of your Echo does not provide start/stop events.

Comment: hmmm... maybe i should buy a harmony hub

Comment: @Helmar you propably answered the question with your comment. Please do post it as answer, too.